# How to count the last 60s in moving window in golang?

Tags: go, goroutine

I want to know if how can I count the number of request based on the moving window in golang after 60s?

Comment: Your question is not clear. What type of requests are you counting? What is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: If you are looking for metrics logging, you may want to checkout out [Prometheus go package](https://prometheus.io/docs/guides/go-application/)

Answer (score 2):

You could use some middleware:

```
import (
    "sync/atomic"
    "net/http"
)

type counter int32

func (c *counter) increment() int32 {
    return atomic.AddInt32((*int32)(c), 1)
}

func (c *counter) decrement() int32 {
    return atomic.AddInt32((*int32)(c), -1)
}

func (c *count32) get() int32 {
    return atomic.LoadInt32((*int32)(c))
}

var c counter

func Last60SecondsMiddleware(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        c.increment()
        next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
        time.AfterFunc(time.Minute, func() {
            c.decrement()
        })
    })
}
```

And then to get the value, you can just call `c.get()`

Comment: this is what i wanted to implement thanks